# Accessing the preview link tooltip data in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, urlfetch

When hovering over a hyperlink in a cell, Google Sheets provides a rich tooltip that fetches and displays information about the linked webpage, including its title and snippet, in a small window.

How can I access this information to save it in another cell?

I'm trying to use it for instagram and Google sheet fetches the info even if I am not logged in to instagram. Additionally, I tried using Google Apps Script but it requires being logged in and overall this solution seems much more complicated.

Is there a way to directly fetch the data from the preview in Google Sheets?

[image]

Comment: What you require is not possible without using web scraping methods. However, using it may violate the terms of service of certain websites. To avoid this, you may want to access the website's API (in this case, Instagram's API) to extract your desired data.